# How do I prepare test cases for Interfaces in JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, interface, junit4

Following is my code for interfaces, and three classes. I use JUNIT testing and the JUnit test class is also below. However I have no idea to pass the parameters from my concrete classes and use it in JUnit class.

**Interface**
ArithmeticSkeleton.java

```
public interface ArithmeticSkeleton {
    int operation(int a, int b);
}
```

**Concrete Class For Division**
Divide.java

```
public class Divide implements ArithmeticSkeleton{
    @Override
    public int operation(int a, int b) {
        return (a / b);
    }
}
```

**Concrete Class For Multiplication**
Multiply.java

```
public class Multiply implements ArithmeticSkeleton{
    @Override
    public int operation(int a, int b) {
        return (a * b);
    }
}
```

**Concrete Class For Addition**
Addition.java

```
 public class Addition implements ArithmeticSkeleton{
        @Override
        public int operation(int a, int b) {
            return (a + b);
        }
    }
```

**JUnit Test Class**
ArithmeticSkeletonTest.java

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public class ArithmeticSkeletonTest {
        public ArithmeticSkeleton asInterface;
        public Divide div;
        public ArithmeticSkeletonTest(ArithmeticSkeleton asInterface) {
            this.asInterface = asInterface;
    }
    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> testInstances(){
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Object[]{new Multiply()},
                new Object[]{new Addition()},
                new Object[]{new Subtraction()},
                new Object[]{new Divide()}
               );
    }   
}
```

**how to test it on ArithmeticSkeletonTest.java**

Comment: Would it be better to have seperate parameterized testcases per concrete implementation and not the interface?  i.e   MutiplyTest, DivideTest etc.  This way you can have parameterised tests with different values in context of the operation being performed

Comment: Agreed. Parameterized tests for the input values, ok, but I would make one concrete test class for every one of those implementation classes. Don't forget: Unit tests are code, too and should be easily understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't test interfaces, you test implementations. In this case, the only contract you have for your interface is that it provide the function `(int a, int b) -> int`, with nothing more specific stated (in particular, is it okay for `b` to be zero?). The compiler ensures that this contract is upheld.

Instead, you should write a test *for each implementing class*, verifying that it performs the operation as expected.

Writers will sometimes say that you should test interfaces and not implementations. What they mean is that your test should interact with the API or contract, also known as the *public interface* of your code (*black-box testing*), and not examine the internal state of the class under test (*white-box testing*). This is not the same as writing all of your tests to a Java `interface` type.

For example, the contract of your `Divide` class says that it should return the quotient of `a` divided by `b`, and your test cases should confirm that this is what happens. However, it's up to your class to decide how to implement that. You can use the `/` operator, but you could also perform iterated subtraction, or you could use `BigInteger.divide()`. Any of these are correct (if not necessarily ideal) implementations of the `Divide` API, and your test should be satisfied with any of them.

Comment: Thank you,
But I clearly read at multiple places including the JUnit 4 Documentation that the testers must write test cases for the interfaces and not the implementations. Please correct me if I am not following something.
@vcetinick

Comment: @ramnarayanan Clarifying.

Comment: @ramnarayanan Testers must write testcases for the interfaces and not the implementations refers to the fact that when mocking the objects while unit testing,if needed, the interface type must be used instead of concrete implementation classes to ensure generality.

Answer (score 0):

You don't test interfaces, you test implementations. So if you have 5 classes that implement an interface, you will need 5 test classes, one for each implementation.  You will find that those 5 classes have much code in common, because all will test that the implementations conform to the contract of the interface. I find it useful to extract that common code into parametric tests in a "test" class for the interface. It does not really "test the interface"; it tests "classes that implement the interface".